# Hyperledger Fabric Endorsement Logic

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I understand that we can set the endorsement policy by executing `peer chaincode instantiate -C <channelid> -n mycc -p "AND('Org1.member', 'Org2.member')"`

But where can we set an algorithm that states what transactions Org1.member signs as valid? Where does it make the decision to say yes or no on the decision?

Is it correct to assume when a chaincode execution fails, that's where a peer will sign the transaction as invalid? 
For instance, if I want Org1.member to sign a transaction as valid only when`x ==1,` would I put in the chaincode `if x != 1; return shim.Error()`? 
Would that be the standard way of using endorsement logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default endorsement logic is quite simple:   if the chaincode executes successfully (meaning the invoked chaincode function does not return an error), then the peer will sign the proposalResponse.